# Objects and comparing

Tags: javascript

I have hit a brick wall with a JS exercise :/. I am trying to Create 3 Person objects, with the attributes "name", "occupation" and "pay", as well as the method "comparePay(person)", which compares the pay values of the object calling it and the object passed to it as argument, then printing the result.

**Expected output.**:
First person's name: Michael
Second person's job: Python-programmer
Third person's pay: 800

Michael earns 3500 more than Lena
Brad earns 700 less than Lena
Brad earns as much as Brad

The objects should have the following values:

Michael, JS-programmer, 5000
Lena, Python-programmer, 1500
Brad, Teacher, 800

I have created a code that prints the first part of the exercise but not able to print the comparisons.  Please see the screenshot for clarification. The grey code below for comparisons are not editable so I wasn't sure how I could print the comparisons as they dont contain the console.log bit. Should I do this by changing the compare Pay() function.
The expected output printing order should be followed to pass, so first the names and details and second the comparisons.

[image: My code Including Grey code]
[image: My output using the code below (Expected output on the right)]

```
 function Person(name, occupation, pay) {
      this.name = name;
      this.occupation = occupation;
      this.pay = pay;
    　this.comparePay = function(person) { /* compare the value of the pay */
         var difference = person.pay - person.pay;
         if (difference > 0) {
             return person.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
         } else if (difference === 0) {
             return person.name + " earns as much as " + person.name;
         } else {
             return person.name + " earns " + Math.abs(difference) + " less than " + person.name;
         } 
        };
    　}

    person1 = new Person("Michael", "JS-programmer", 5000);
    person2 = new Person("Lena", "Python-programmer", 1500);
    person3 = new Person("Brad", "Teacher", 800);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.pay - person.pay`?

Comment: @MajorProductions It gives me the same output XD.

Comment: You didn't **output** the result of the comparisons.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: ^ see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What @Major Productions mentioned in his comment is correct. You need to reference current object as this.

```js
function Person(name, occupation, pay) {
  this.name = name;
  this.occupation = occupation;
  this.pay = pay;
  this.comparePay = function(person) {
    /* compare the value of the pay */
    var difference = this.pay - person.pay;
    if (difference > 0) {
      console.log(this.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name);
    } else if (difference === 0) {
      console.log(this.name + " earns as much as " + person.name);
    } else {
      console.log(this.name + " earns " + Math.abs(difference) + " less than " + person.name);
    }
  };
}

person1 = new Person("Michael", "JS-programmer", 5000);
person2 = new Person("Lena", "Python-programmer", 1500);
person3 = new Person("Brad", "Teacher", 800);


console.log("First person's name: " + person1.name);
console.log("Second person's occupation: " + person2.occupation);
console.log("Third person's pay: " + person3.pay);

person1.comparePay(person2);
person3.comparePay(person2);
person3.comparePay(person3);
```

Comment: This is correct, however the reason I pasted a screen shot is to show that the grey code is something I cant edit. The question locks that part of the code and only can write above. Is there a method to print the comparisons using the grey code above?

Comment: Edited answer to not touch grey code

Comment: @H.Ach Do you understand what went wrong with your code? 1. You not comparing `this.pay` and `person.pay`, but only referenced `person.pay`. Both to calculate the difference in pay, but also when creating the output string. 2. The `console.log()` statements have to be placed inside `comparePay()`, since the grey code doesn't do any logging regarding the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
   function Person(name, occupation, pay) {
      this.name = name;
      this.occupation = occupation;
      this.pay = pay;
    　this.comparePay = function(person) { /* compare the value of the pay */
         var difference = this.pay - person.pay;
         var comparison = "";
         if (difference > 0) {
             comparison = person.name + " earns " + difference + " more than " + person.name;
         } else if (difference === 0) {
             comparison = person.name + " earns as much as " + person.name;
         } else {
             comparison = person.name + " earns " + Math.abs(difference) + " less than " + person.name;
         } 
         console.log(comparison);
         return comparison;
        };
    　}
```

Comment: I have tried this already on top of the grey code. The comparison is then printed before the details part, which is not the desired output.

Comment: What do you mean by details?

Comment: The part of the code that prints the name, job and pay

Comment: Edited my answer. Do it like that

Comment: let me know if there are still any questions @H.Ach

Comment: This is correct however I need to use the grey code in the screenshot to output the results. That is why I included the screenshot.

Comment: Ah ok, so save the return into an local variable and then after the if statement make console.log and after that return the variable